# How do iterators know what item comes next?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

As far as I understood it, iterators use lazy evaluation, meaning that they don't actually save each item in memory, but just contain the instructions on how to generate the next item.

However, let's say I have some list `[1,2,3,4,5]` and convert it into an iterator doing `a = iter([1,2,3,4,5])`.

Now, if iterators are supposed to save memory space because as said they contain the instructions on how to generate the next item that is requested, how do they do it in this example? How is the iterator `a` we created supposed to know what item comes next, without saving the entire list to memory?

Comment: Would make sense if each value stored it's neighbours, so you'd get a linked list and that's how you "knew" what's next by keeping a reference to your  next item. Or just allocated a set of memory range and you just stepped one step in the memory block.

Comment: Iterators *can* save memory, if they can generate their elements from a seed value. An instance of `list_iterator` does *not* generate its values, though; it retrieves them from an underlying `list` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the iterator does in fact store a reference to the underlying `list` (along with the present index) internally, so it is keeping the `list` alive. For iterators that don't use memory, look at generators or iterators backed by lazy types like `range`, both of which can store just enough information to produce the next value and the information on the end condition, without storing all the values up front.

A generator like:

```
def makes_numbers(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

essentially freezes the state of the frame variables (`i`, `n`, and the current instruction) on each `yield`, producing 1 through 5 without actually storing all of them at once. `range` itself is basically a lazy sequence that, when an iterator is constructed from it, performs the same work internally (but in a more optimized fashion).

Comment: I could get the same result by replacing ```yield``` with ```print()```, if I wanted to print ```i``` anyways, right?

Comment: @NB575: Sure, but `yield`ed values are programmatically useful, while `print` is fire-and-forget; it went "somewhere", but you can't do much of anything with it after that.

Comment: Meaning you would use ```yield``` when you are planning on doing other things with the generator when iterating over it than just printing the values, right?

Comment: @NB575: Exactly.

Comment: @NB575: To be clear, if the function used `print` instead of `yield`, it would run eagerly; as soon as it was called, it would do all the work (no ability to do part of the work or defer it). With `yield`, it does nothing when called (except cache the `n` passed and set up the stack frame), and it only computes and produces the value as you iterate it. So you could do `gen = makes_numbers(5)`, then `print(next(gen))` and print only the first number produced, not the other four (which would remain available if you advanced the generator further).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, that means that iterating over it and printing each item then. and instead of yielding just printing the item right away, has the same memory efficiency?

Answer (score 4):

> How is the iterator a we created supposed to know what item comes next, without saving the entire list to memory?

It doesn't save the list. It just stores a reference to the list you passed in.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a = iter(l)
>>> next(a)
1

>>> l[1] = 1337
>>> next(a)
1337
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think for a moment about this scenario ... You have a file of over a million elements, loading the memory of the whole list of elements would be really expensive. By using an iterator, you can avoid making the program heavy by opening the file once and extracting only one element for the computation. You would save a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Although, ShadowRanger explained answer well. Let me allow it to explain using an example.
Every iterator must have these two methods.

```
 __init__()
 __next__()
```

**next** method must return the next value.

```
class My_iterator:
  def __iter__(self):
    self.x = 1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    y = self.x
    self.x += 1
    return y
```

Above, you can see that this method is computing next iterator or more precisely generating next iterator (ShadowRanger explained this above.)
If you are using a list then it keeps a reference to it.